# How to retrieve all the attribute / namespace of particular xml element c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using the below xml file I want to get all the attributes of `<package`>/namespace of  element . How to get those namespace in XmlSerializerNamespaces or XPath to get this element alone

Expected Output

```
<package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"nxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Tried:

C#

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(file.xml);
XNamespace ns = document.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var results = document.Root.Elements().Select(x => x.Element("package").GetDefaultNamespace());
var result = document.XPathSelectElement("package").GetDefaultNamespace();
```

For this XML

```
  <package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"nxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
    <example>
      ...
    </example>
  </package>
```

Please help!

Comment: Give an example for what you need

Comment: I want this element <package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"nxmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: Try : var results = document.Descendants(ns + "package").ToList();

Comment: Here's an idea: a "default namespace" is a namespace without prefix (`xmlns="URI"`), so it's applied to all un-prefixed elements in the XML. Your `xmlns:xsd="URI"` and `xmlns:xsi="URI"` (also, the `n` in `nxmlns:xsi` and also missing a space in front of it is likely a typo) are not default namespaces. No idea how to get the list of namespaces in C#. These namespaces are not regular attributes (as `xmlns` is a reserved name/prefix). XPath queries typically via the qualified (= prefixed) element name.